# CSRF token in Angular 4 CLI from Django

Tags: django, angular

I created a full-stack app with Angular, Node, Express and Postgres:
https://github.com/shivkiyer/database-app

Now I am trying to learn Django by repeating the project with Django on the backend instead of Node JS. The entire code is here:
https://github.com/shivkiyer/djangoangular

I am not able to extract the CSRF token sent by Django in Angular so that I can send it back when I submit a POST form.

In Django, I have these two views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from . import models, forms

# Create your views here.

def basic_list(request):
    print(request)
    customer_list = []
    for customer_item in models.Customer.objects.all():
        customer_list.append({
            "first_name": customer_item.first_name,
            "last_name": customer_item.last_name,
            "city": customer_item.city
        })
    print(customer_list)
    return JsonResponse(customer_list, safe=False)

def empty_form(request):
    print(request)
    return HttpResponse("Form received")
```

In my settings.py file I have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' enabled. I checked out the Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/

I tried adding several options in settings.py file:

```
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'content-type',
    'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
)

CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = [
    'content-type',
    'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN']
```

My Angular component has:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  sample_form: FormGroup;
  server_token: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.sample_form = new FormGroup({
      'first_name': new FormControl(null),
      'last_name': new FormControl(null)
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  viewCustomers() {
    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/list/')
        .subscribe((response: Response) => {
          console.log(response.headers.keys());
          this.server_token = response.headers.get('http_x_csrftoken');
          console.log(response.headers.get('http_x_csrftoken'));
          console.log(response.json());
        });
  }

  send_sample_form() {
    let my_headers = new Headers({'x-csrftoken': this.server_token});
    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/emptyform/',
          {'my_form': this.sample_form.value},
          {headers: this.server_token})
          .subscribe(
            (response) => {
              console.log(response.headers.keys());
              console.log(response);
            }
          );
  }

}
```

I am not able to extract the CSRF token from the header. The command:
    console.log(response.headers.keys());

Displays only the header content-type. How do I get this token and send it back to Django in a POST request. When I disable 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in settings.py then it works. So there is no other cross-site issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be helpful to you: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: It is for Angular 5 HttpClient only? With Angular 4 Http, it just says observe is not in RequestOptions. And the docs for Http doesn't mention that either.

Comment: I just saw now that you are using `Http` and not `HttpClient`. If you are using Angular 4.3 or higher, consider moving to `HttpClient`. `Http` will go away in the future. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: I am using Angular 4.2.4. So I will have to upgrade. Will do that and try.

Comment: I updated Angular and tried the block of code in the link. But I still get only one header "content-type". Does Django insert the CSRF token somewhere else?

Comment: I couldn't say. Makes me wonder if it ends up in a cookie instead of a header. Perhaps [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection) is something that you need to do, too. I am just guessing now. Good luck!

Comment: I think I will post a separate question on trying to extract this cookie/header that Django sends out. When you using Django Template Library the {% csrf_token %} is all you need.