# CSRF tokens from Angular 4 to Django

Tags: django, angular, cookies, csrf

This is a follow-up question to a question I asked yesterday:
[CSRF token in Angular 4 CLI from Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066627/csrf-token-in-angular-4-cli-from-django?noredirect=1#comment87154719_50066627)

I have a backend Django server and a frontend Angular app. I am trying to submit a form in Angular to the Django backend with a POST. The problem is with CSRF tokens.

This is the Django view:

```
#@csrf_exempt
def empty_form(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        message = "Post"
    else:
        message = "Get"
    return JsonResponse({'message': message})
```

And this is the Angular component:

```
send_sample_form() {

  let d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  let expires:string = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  let cpath:string = '/';
  // this.cookieService.set('csrftoken', this.server_token, d, cpath, '127.0.0.1', false);
  this.cookieService.set('csrftoken', this.server_token);
  let my_headers = new HttpHeaders(
    {
      'X-CSRFToken': this.server_token
    }
  );
  this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/emptyform/',
        {'my_form': this.sample_form.value},
        {headers: this.server_token, withCredentials: true})
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
            console.log(response);
          }
        );
}
```

When the Angular and Django are separate servers (localhost:4200 and 127.0.0.1:8000), the angular code does not get the CSRF token. When I run it in production mode and so there is only the Django server at 127.0.0.1:8000, now the Angular component is able to extract the CSRF token with:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/generate_token/', { observe: 'response' })
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.server_token = this.cookieService.get('csrftoken');
          console.log(this.server_token);
        });
}
```

But I have tried every possible version of the set() method of Cookie Service and am still getting a 403 from Django.

this.cookieService.set('csrftoken', this.server_token, d, cpath, '127.0.0.1', false);
or
this.cookieService.set('csrftoken', this.server_token);

To just check the Django server, I used Postman to send requests to my Django server. A get request gives me a CSRF token. And when I do a POST request, I need a CSRF cookie and a header 'X-CSRFToken' to get back a status 200 or I get a 403. So the Django server CSRF middleware seems to be working as it does give a 200 back when a request has a  CSRF cookie and an XCSRFToken header.

I was trying to think if I can check in the Django view function if the request has the right CSRF cookie from the Angular frontend. I used 'csrf_exempt' to let the POST go through and was trying to find a way to extract the CSRF cookie and do a visual check but couldn't find a way to do that. Is there a way to extract a CSRF cookie in a Django view and print it out? Like?

print(request['csrftoken'])

The entire code is on my GitHub:
https://github.com/shivkiyer/djangoangular

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this: `print(request.COOKIES['csrftoken'])`

Comment: The CSRF token in the Django view is identical to what the Angular code outputs in console. But still I get a 403. So what else do I need to do? The is the error in the command line "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)"

Comment: Do you receive a correct `x-csrftoken` header as well?

Comment: I did a print(request.META) and there is no x-csrftoken. In my Angular, I am adding it with {headers: my_headers} option in the POST request with my_headers=new HttpHeaders('X-CSRFToken': this.server_token). Why is Angular not adding the header when this is specified?